# Odd C++ operator precedence

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why this makes sense (note that `heap` is a `vector<int>`):

```
// Heap Sort
int parent = 0;
int leftChild = (parent * 2) + 1;
int rightChild = (parent * 2) + 2;

// This conditional works fine. Code doesn't enter block when heap.size() is zero.
while (leftChild < heap.size()) {}
```

However:

```
// Code does enter this block when heap.size() is 0? Why?
while (leftChild < (heap.size() - 1) {}
```

I get the sense that this is occurring because `-1` is somehow being interpreted as 'truthy', but I don't understand how `leftChild` (which by default is `1` can ever be less than `0` or `-1`.

Comment: Hint: `heap.size()` is an unsigned integer.

Comment: Gaaaaahhh. Really... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`heap.size()` returns an `std::size_t`, which is typedef'd to be an `unsigned int`.  `((unsigned int)0)-1` is still an `unsigned int` that is equal to the maximum value for an `unsigned int`.  Thus, `leftChild` will always be less than `heap.size() - 1` unless it happens to be equal to `0xFFFFFFFF` (for 32-bit ints).